# Have one servlet that does not renew the user's java session

Tags: java, servlets, gwt-rpc

I have a servlet (GWT-RPC servlet) that is only used to check if the user session has been cleared (by looking and seeing if the session variables are null).

The problem is that when this runs on a timer in the user's browser each request to check if the session is cleared is renewing the session timoue for another 30 minutes.  I could try to make the timer request be less often than the session timeout.  For example if sessions expire every 30 minutes and I check ever 35 minutes it would take a maximum of 70 minutes to finally properly detect that the session has died.

Does anybody know of a way to have a servlet request not renew the session?

Comment: Will disabling session creation for that particular jsp would work?

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet specification requires that any request that accesses the session updates the session's last accessed time and hence prolongs the life of the session. The 'right' solution depends on what exactly why you need to know if the session has expired. I suspect that hwat you really want is a `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`

Comment: I need to be able to have a client side timer in an all-javascript application (via GWT) detect that your session has ended and display a popup to warn of this or redirect to the login page.

Comment: Session listeners aren't going to help you then.You approach looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution for now...

Create a servlet filter that updates a session variable called "CUSTOM_LAST_SESSION_ACCESS".  Any request to the webapp updates this variable to the current timestamp.

Have a Javascript timer check via ajax if that varaible has been updated in the last 30 minutes, if not invalidate the session.

This means sessions are invalidated via javascript call if you never close your browser.  If you close your browser the standard Java session cleanup happens as no HTTP requests have happened in over 30 minutes.